A problem about fundamental region of a lattice

This lemma is from Peikert and Carter's handout of lecture 2. $\mathbf{\tilde{B}}$ is the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalized matrix of $\mathbf{B}$. I want to prove this lemma.
My idea is to prove it by contradiction: if the body $\mathcal{P}({\mathbf{\tilde{B}}})$ is not a fundamental region of $\mathcal{L}$, there must be some "gaps" and "overlaps" in $\mathbb{R}^n$. W.l.o.g we assume there is a vector $\mathbf{v}$ is in some "gaps" s.t. $\mathbf{v}\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{B})$ but $\mathbf{v}\notin \mathbf{x}+\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{\tilde{B}})$ for any $\mathbf{x}\in\mathcal{L}$. So, we need to use this vector to find a contradiction. We know that $\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{By}$ for some $\mathbf{y}\in[-1/2,1/2)^n$ and $\mathbf{B}=\mathbf{\tilde{B}}\mathbf{U}$ for some upper unitriangular $\mathbf{U}$, and therefore, $\mathbf{v=\mathbf{\tilde{B}}Uy}$. Next, we need to "extract" a $\mathbf{x}\in\mathcal{L}$ s.t. $\mathbf{v=\mathbf{\tilde{B}}y'+x}$ where $\mathbf{y'}\in[-1/2,1/2)^n$. But I can not figure out how to make it!

You should probably define $\tilde{\mathbf{B}}$.

I come up with satisfactory proof (for me), but not so formal:)
Let $\mathcal{L}=\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{B})$.
Since $|\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{\tilde{B}})|=|\det(\mathcal{L})|=|\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{{B}})|$ and $\mathcal{L}+\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{{B}})$ is a partition of $\mathbb{Z}^n$, if $\mathcal{L}+\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{\tilde{B}})$ is not a partition of $\mathbb{Z}^n$, then, there must be some overlaps, i.e., for some $\mathbf{x,y}\in\mathcal{L}$ s.t. $(\mathbf{x}+\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{\tilde{B}}))\cap(\mathbf{y}+\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{\tilde{B}}))=S\ne\emptyset$. Since $\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{\tilde{B}})$ is a convex and $\mathbf{v}+\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{\tilde{B}})$ is a translation of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{\tilde{B}})$ for any $\mathbf{v}\in\mathcal{L}$, the midpoint of the line connecting $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ must be in $S$, i.e., $(\mathbf{x+y})/2\in S$.
We translate the vector $\mathbf{x}$ to the original point and translate the vector $\mathbf{y}$ with same amount, i.e., $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\to \mathbf{0},\mathbf{y-x}$, and $S'={S}-\mathbf{x}$. Let $\mathbf{y'=y-x}$:

Case 1: $\mathbf{y}'\in\{\mathbf{b}_1,\mathbf{b}_2,\dots,\mathbf{b}_n\}$, where $[\mathbf{b}_1\mid \mathbf{b}_2\mid \dots\mid \mathbf{b}_n]=\mathbf{B}$. We let $\mathbf{y}'=\mathbf{b}_i$, then $\mathbf{y}'/2=\mathbf{b}_i/2$. We know that according to the definition of vectors $\mathbf{\tilde{b}}_i$, it is orthogonal to $\mathrm{span}(\mathbf{b}_1,\mathbf{b}_2,\dots,\mathbf{b}_{i-1})$; so in the direction of $\mathbf{\tilde{b}}_i$, $\mathbf{0}$ must be translated $\|\mathbf{\tilde{b}}_i\|$ to get to the plane of $\mathbf{b}_i$ which is parallel to $\mathrm{span}(\mathbf{b}_1,\mathbf{b}_2,\dots,\mathbf{b}_{i-1})$! Therefore, $\mathbf{y}'/2=\mathbf{b}_i/2$ must be translated $\|\mathbf{\tilde{b}}_i\|/2$ to get to the same plane, which means, $\mathbf{y}'/2$ must be in one border of $\mathbf{y}'+\mathbf{\tilde{B}}[-1/2,1/2)^n$ (note that $\mathbf{y}'/2=[y_1/2,y_2/2,\dots,\|\mathbf{\tilde{b}}_i\|/2,\dots,y_n/2]^t$), and $\mathbf{y}'/2\notin \mathbf{\tilde{B}}[-1/2,1/2)^n$. This result contradicts the assumption that the middle point $\mathbf{y}'/2$ is in the set $S'$.
Case 2: $\mathbf{y}'\notin\{\mathbf{b}_1,\mathbf{b}_2,\dots,\mathbf{b}_n\}$. We can easily transform the base $\mathbf{B}$ by multiply a unimodular matrix $\mathbf{U}$ to let some $\mathbf{b}'_i=\mathbf{y}'$ for some vector $\mathbf{b}'_i\in\mathbf{BU}$.

As mentioned at the beginning, the proof is not formal. I need to learn more about it.

I don't think all of your notation is fully defined, so your current proof attempt is pretty hard to follow. I'll give you the following hint though ---
we know that $\mathbb{Z}^n + [-1/2, 1/2)^n = \mathbb{R}^n$ is a partition (or in other words, $[-1/2, 1/2)^n$ is a fundamental region of $\mathbb{Z}^n$). What does that imply about
$$\mathbf{B}\cdot (\mathbb{Z}^n + [-1/2, 1/2)^n) = \mathcal{L}(\mathbf{B}) + \mathbf{B}\cdot [-1/2, 1/2)^n$$
